# lua-visual-debug package seems to be broken on MacTeX 2016

Tags: luatex, lua-visual-debug

I'm trying to use the package for the first time, and I'm not having any success. Here's my input (hello.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

And I'm compiling via `lualatex hello`.

Here's the console output:

```
$ lualatex hello
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./hello.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debu
g.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)))
No file hello.aux.
...mf-dist/tex/luatex/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.lua:139: attempt to com
pare nil with number
stack traceback:
        ...mf-dist/tex/luatex/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.lua:139: in function '
show_page_elements'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
<argument> ...ow_page_elements(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"])}

l.5 \end{document}

?
```

The copy of lua-visual-debug.lua that ships with MacTeX 2016 appears to be 0.4.

Comment: Placing the latest lua-visual-debug.lua (from github) in my current directory resolved the error.

Comment: I have not tested with texlive2016 yet. I will download it and fix the package. It might take a week. - BTW: please report the bugs directly to me (the mail address is in the Readme and in the documentation). I don't visit tex.sx regularly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized (in the neare future, this question has no relevance)

Comment: I'm fine with the question being closed, but I disagree with the reason being "off-topic". It's not like I was asking a question about turtles. ;)

Comment: There used to be the 'too localized' issue for questions like these (future visitors will not benefit from the question), so I closed it as off topic. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons You might be correct that under the new terms, the question should not be marked as “off topic”. Do you have an opinion if we should re-open the question?

Comment: No need to re-open the question. Although, it does contain very useful info for future visitors that's not overly specify (i.e. that tlmgr and TeX Live Utility exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacTeX-2016 installs a full TeX Live 2016 which was distributed in June, 2016. Since then there have been many updates. Have you used TeX Live Utility (or the lower level tlmgr) to update your TeX Live? I seem to have 0.5.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a software update mechanism built into TeX Live! I thought I'd have to wait a year before the next update.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this on texlive2016 and it works without problems. So this could be something special about MacTeX 2016, which I don't have installed here.

Judging from the error message, MacTeX has an old version (0.4) of lua-visual-debug. You should contact the MacTeX developers.

Comment: I think MacTeX is just TeX Live with some extra stuff, so likely one could just update the package with the TeX Live Utility  ([How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55438)).

Comment: MacTeX-2016 installs a full TeX Live 2016 which was distributed in June, 2016. Since then there have been many updates. Have you used TeX Live Utility (or the lower level tlmgr) to update your TeX Live? I seem to have 0.5.